# inner join ambiguous column name: id

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to search in my db, but the error

`ambiguous column name: id (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT placa, modelo, fabricante, cor FROM carros INNER JOIN carroCliente ON id = carro WHERE cliente = ?`

shows up, what am I doing wrong? I've been searching all day and did not find anything here.

My method:

```
public void buscarDados(){
        cursor = getDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT " + DatabaseHelper.Carros.PLACA + ", " + DatabaseHelper.Carros.MODELO + ", "
                + DatabaseHelper.Carros.FABRICANTE + ", " + DatabaseHelper.Carros.COR +  " FROM " + DatabaseHelper.Carros.TABELA_CARROS
                + " INNER JOIN " + DatabaseHelper.CarroCliente.TABELA_CARROCLIENTE +
                " ON " + DatabaseHelper.Carros.ID + " = " + DatabaseHelper.CarroCliente.ID_CARRO
                + " WHERE " + DatabaseHelper.CarroCliente.ID_CLIENTE + " = ?", new String[] {Integer.toString(buscarIdCliente())});

        if(cursor!=null){
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use Reference for both the tables

Comment: both tables have id columns `ambiguous column name: id (code 1):` error

Comment: but i am using, or not?

Comment: what is the value of `DatabaseHelper.Carros.ID` and `DatabaseHelper.CarroCliente.ID_CARRO`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Reference for both the tables, both tables have id columns ambiguous `column name: id (code 1)` error

```
public void buscarDados(){
        cursor = getDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT A." + DatabaseHelper.Carros.PLACA + ", A." + DatabaseHelper.Carros.MODELO + ", A."
                + DatabaseHelper.Carros.FABRICANTE + ", A." + DatabaseHelper.Carros.COR +  " FROM " + DatabaseHelper.Carros.TABELA_CARROS
                + " as A INNER JOIN " + DatabaseHelper.CarroCliente.TABELA_CARROCLIENTE +
                " as B ON A." + DatabaseHelper.Carros.ID + " = B." + DatabaseHelper.CarroCliente.ID_CARRO
                + " WHERE B." + DatabaseHelper.CarroCliente.ID_CLIENTE + " = ?", new String[] {Integer.toString(buscarIdCliente())});

        if(cursor!=null){
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please avoid "code-only" answers. It is not the point of StackOverflow to provide code for free, but answering questions and explaining problems to help understanding.

Comment: @Yunnosch I have explain problem on question comment section

Comment: Good. Now add that explanation to the answer, to make it useful and readable in itself. That way it becomes also helpful for other readers with similar problems, without requiring them to follow the chronology of the conversation.

Answer (score 2):

As @Akhilesh mentioned in his comment, your error is probably being caused due to both tables having an `id` column defined.  You can get around this by using explicit aliases to limit the scope of each column:

```
SELECT
    t1.placa,
    t1.modelo,
    t1.fabricante,
    t1.cor
FROM carros t1               -- explicitly specify which 'id' column you are referring to
INNER JOIN carroCliente t2
    ON t1.id = t2.carro
WHERE t2.cliente = ?
```

The other answers gave Java code, but I think a raw query is actually more appropriate here because it shows how you can use aliases to fix your problem.  Actually, it is always a good idea to use aliases in your query, because it makes the query less terse and easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use syntax as gicen below;

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;
```

In your example ;

```
public void buscarDados(){
        cursor = getDatabase().rawQuery(
        "SELECT DatabaseHelper.Carros.PLACA, DatabaseHelper.Carros.MODELO, "
                + "DatabaseHelper.Carros.FABRICANTE , DatabaseHelper.Carros.COR FROM DatabaseHelper.Carros.TABELA_CARROS "
                + " INNER JOIN  DatabaseHelper.CarroCliente.TABELA_CARROCLIENTE  ON " 
        + " DatabaseHelper.Carros.ID = '" + DatabaseHelper.CarroCliente.ID_CARRO + "' "
                + " WHERE DatabaseHelper.CarroCliente.ID_CLIENTE  = '", new String[] {Integer.toString(buscarIdCliente())} + "'" ); 
       if(cursor!=null){
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to give each table a name like

```
SELECT st.id FROM student st INNER JOIN attendance at ON at.id = st.id;
```

Something like this. So, it can be identified that which table's id you are trying to access.
If you get confused, than try preparing query in and DBMS tool first, than write code for that query.